# How to use the text attribute from options in a form select with V-Model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I currently have a vue bootstrap form with several inputs, one being a select.

```
        <b-form-select id="myInput"
                  :options="listOfOptions"
                  v-model="form.selection"
                  required>
        </b-form-select>
```

With options being:

```
                listOfOptions: [                  
                { 
                    text: 'Option A', 
                    value: 'A'
                },
                { 
                    text: 'Option B', 
                    value: 'B' 
                },
                { 
                    text: 'Option C', 
                    value: 'C' 
                },
               ],
```

As expected, when I select one, it sets form.selection to the value I have chosen, so if I select 'Option C', form.selection is set too 'C'.

I now have another requirement. I need to assign the value of text to a new variable in form, lets call it name. So when I select 'Option B' form.selection = 'B' and form.name = 'Option B'. I've been playing around, but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Dunno about those frameworks, but you might need a change listener like `this.form.name.value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text`.

Comment: I think computed property or a watcher the explicitly assigns this is a way to go. WDYT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap select component is designed this way and if want to has the **text** as part of data that you select, you must change the source:

```
  listOfOptions: [                  
            { 
                text: 'Option A', 
                value: {
                   text: 'Option A', 
                   value: 'A'
                }
            },
            ...
  ]
```

Now, `form.selection` is an object that you have them.

Comment: Worked a treat, meant that I couldn't just use the form object as JSON for my API as I had to handle the two objects, but thanks very much!